# How to know the file count when uploading via multipart form-data in java

Tags: java, file-upload, playframework, count, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple files using multipart form-data in java and I am using play framework.

`Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
 files=body.getFiles();`

But I may have more than 1 file and I need to know the count of files in body.

I got the file count using a for loop.

But Is there a better way to get the file count without using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
int fileCount = files.size();
```

Here fileCount will give you number of files you have.

Comment: Even in my method if i add `int fileCount = files.size()` i get the file count.
Anyways thank you